# Real-valued dimension

Tags: abstract-algebra, dimension-theory-algebra

Let $\overline{\mathbb{R}}_{\geq 0} = \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \cup \{\infty\}$.

Given a commutative ring with unity $R$, $R\operatorname{-Mod}$ denotes the category of $R$-modules.

Given $R$-modules $A$ and $B$, $A \cong B$ denotes isomorphism of $A$ and $B$ as $R$-modules.

---

Does there exist an example of the following?

- A commutative ring with unity $R$
- A mapping $\operatorname{d}: R\operatorname{-Mod} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}_{\geq 0}$ with the following properties:

  - If $A \cong B$, $\operatorname{d}(A) = \operatorname{d}(B)$
  - $\operatorname{d}(\{0\}) = 0$
  - $\operatorname{d}(R) = 1$
  - $\operatorname{d}(A \oplus B) = \operatorname{d}(A) + \operatorname{d}(B)$
  - $\operatorname{d}(A \otimes_R B) = \operatorname{d}(A) \cdot \operatorname{d}(B)$
  - If $A \subseteq B$ is a submodule, then $\operatorname{d}(A) \leq \operatorname{d}(B)$
  - If $A \subseteq B$ is a submodule, then $\operatorname{d}(B/A) \leq \operatorname{d}(B)$
  - If $A \subseteq B$ is a submodule, then $\operatorname{d}(A) + \operatorname{d}(B/A) = \operatorname{d}(B)$
  - $\operatorname{d}$ is surjective

The idea is that $\operatorname{d}$ would be analogous to the dimension $\operatorname{dim}$ in the case that $R$ is a field. However, fields do not satisfy the condition since then $\operatorname{dim}$ only takes values in $\overline{\mathbb{N}}_{\geq 0}$ and is therefore not surjective as a mapping to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: I would appreciate constructive feedback on this question in the [Helpful Commentary Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141365/helpful-commentary)

Comment: This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but perhaps somewhat relevant: In operator algebras, modules over a II$_1$ factor admit a dimension function with range $\overline{\mathbb{R}}_{\geq 0}$. It satisfies all the conditions you listed except that the ring is not commutative and the tensor product condition, mainly because there isn't a suitable notion of tensor products. (But if $B$ is just a regular Hilbert space and $\mathrm{d}(B)$ is interpreted as the usual $\overline{\mathbb{N}}_{\geq 0}$-valued dimension of $B$, then that condition is also satisfied.)

Comment: @DavidGao Can you give me a reference?

Comment: This can be found in Chapter 8 of https://www.math.ucla.edu/~popa/Books/IIunV15.pdf

Comment: Unexplained notations: what is R-Mod? what is $\cong$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $R \operatorname{-Mod}$ is the category of $R$-modules and $\cong$ denotes isomorphism as $R$-modules. I think these notations are standard enough that I don't need to include them in the question itself.

Comment: To paraphrase Patrick Gallagher, they are well-known to those who well-know them. But, to the rest of us....

Comment: @GerryMyerson I've added an explanation for the notation in the question.